# How to design an UIScrollView in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a `UIScrollView` that has an embedded `UIView` within it. The `UIView` is set to have a vertical height of 1000. Further, there is a button that is centered horizontally and set to have be 20 units from the bottom edge of `UIView`. Everything works as expected but I am unable to design in storyboard for such a scenario. See screenshot below. The contents outside the screensize are not visible - how does one see / scroll the view into place

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Storyboard:

- Select the ViewController
- Set its `Simulated Size` to `freeform` and height to `1000`.

[image]

Comment: One additional question - if you see the scroll view, there is a space at the top. This is baffling me. The top constraint of the scroll view has been set to be equal to the top of the containing view but the storyboard still shows a gap. Any particular reason for this?

Comment: Maybe scroll view insets. Select the VC, untick Adust Scroll View Insets`.