# how to add more prototype cells in a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

Unable to add more prototype cells after the view's height is reached.
How to add more prototype cells on the view. Please find the image below to see my problem[image]

How to add more prototype cells after that . I am not able to scroll.
Please suggest.

Comment: There is an editor attached to your static table view where you can specify the number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can scroll the table view in interface builder (drag with 2
   fingers on the track pad while over the tableview)
2. You can select the current cell in the document outline on the left; you can also drag more cells or copy paste and existing cell in the document outline
3. You can increase the preview size of the table view to a nonstandard arbitrary height by selecting the ViewController (the yellow circle with the square), clicking the size inspector (5th tab in right pane, icon looks like a ruler) and changing the simulated size to freeform.  Make the height as big as you need to fit.

Comment: I have one more question if you can answer. I have prototype cells as dropdown,textbox,multiselect,textarea etc. When i click on any cell it go to another view and get the value from that view from all controls. I have written delegate methods to get the values. Everything is working fine except the below function executing 3 times func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
       return  elementsData.count  //elementsArray.count

    }

Comment: I was not aware of 1). Is this possible without track pad also? Some key + mouse?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the number of Prototype Cells in the `UITableViews` inspector:

[image]

If you can not see all items, resize it in Storyboard. [Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873864/how-to-design-an-uiscrollview-in-storyboard/40874056#40874056)

Comment: I know that. My question is if i set it to 25. I am able to see only the first 12 cells after that all are not visible. I am not able to scroll.

Comment: I am not able to add any controls like button ,label in those cells as i am not able to scroll it

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood. Updated answer.

Comment: Recently, I've found that the 'Prototype Cells' box isn't showing up any more. Not sure if this is a bug or if the process has changed.

Comment: N.B. may be due to tableview being in a NIB rather than a Storyboard. Could've sworn this used to work just fine.