# How to show the covered part of a static scrollView in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a big static scrollView in my view controller. I can only see small part of it cause the screen is too small. How can i see the slideable, covered part.

Comment: scrollview doesn't scroll?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873864/how-to-design-an-uiscrollview-in-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

In attribute inspector, 4th option - size inspector. Change it from fixed to freedom and increase height as you want